# Fetch excel files from FTP server and save in Google Drive

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, ftp

The requirement is to upload an excel file to Google Drive which file is initially being stored on an FTP server.

I would like to know if it is Possible achieving this through Google App Script. If not App script, is there any way in which we can fetch files from the FTP server and then upload it to Google Drive.

I found out about the **Class UrlFetchApp**.

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.google.com/");
```

makes request to fetch url.

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://example.com/upload_form.cgi", parameters);
```

Makes a request to fetch a URL using optional advanced parameters.

I don't know if the above 2 methods would be of any use.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found on this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/tqmLjdQ3FOw) that **`FTP access is currently unavailable for Google Drive`**.

But I found a [tutorial](https://www.multcloud.com/tutorials/connect-google-drive-to-ftp-1004.html) here that can connect or integrate Google Drive to FTP. This tutorial use a [`multiple cloud storage manager`](https://www.multcloud.com/tutorials/multiple-cloud-storage-manager.html) that easily combine the two services together.

So if you are interested with it, just read the tutorial link to know more about **MultCloud**.

Comment: Thanks! I've already done my bit of research about the multiple cloud storage manager, and it is not an option i'm looking for. Thanks anyways.

Comment: You're welcome, unfortunately FTP access is currently unavailable for Google Drive :(